# Is it possible to split HTML view and Python back-end across different servers (IIS) in Django?

Tags: python, django, iis

I have a `Django` application where I want to separate the `HTML` views and the `Python` back-end logic into two different servers for architectural and security reasons. Specifically, I want one server to handle all the `HTML` rendering and another server to handle the Python back-end logic like database queries, API calls, etc.

Is it possible to do this while still leveraging Django's capabilities? If so, how can I achieve this split?
If it is not doable, may you explain why ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the Django framework is designed to handle both front-end and back-end in one application, it is designed to be inseparable. This means that when a request is received, the backend tasks are executed and the corresponding HTML response is generated using the template. This approach is typically used in small application development where the amount of data per view is relatively small.

But Django is a flexible web framework that allows you to choose how to organize and design the front-end and back-end parts of your application. So it is completely possible to separate the front end and back end.

Django provides powerful back-end functions, including database models, views, routing, form processing, user authentication, and more. These features can be used to build the backend portion of a web application, but it does not limit how you design the frontend.

Many developers choose to use Django with modern front-end frameworks such as  React, Vue.js, or Angular to build single-page applications (SPA) or front-end and back-end separated applications.

In this case, Django's backend is still responsible for handling business logic and data storage, but the frontend is completely designed and implemented by an independent frontend team or developer.

Since your front-end and back-end will be on different servers (perhaps different domains or ports), you need to configure Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to allow the front-end server to make requests to the back-end server. Django has a package called django-cors-headers that can help with this problem.

You can refer to this example: [Separating frontend from backend using Angular and Django](https://humberto.io/blog/separating-frontend-from-backend-with-angular-and-django/).

Comment: Thank you really much it is really usefull.